# How to copy Common name to subject alternative name using openssl.cnf or through openssl cmd

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, subject-alternative-name

Facing an issue in copying common name passed by users to subject alternative name .

Copying common name with static value is working fine .

Need to copy common name with value as supplied.

I tried ${policy_anything::commonName}

Where san result as value supplied